# How to implement Infinite Scrolling using Node.js, Angular.js and Firebase?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**UPDATE 8:**

**CODE:**

```
<% include ../partials/header %>


<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebase-util/0.2.5/firebase-util.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.4/angularfire.min.js"></script>

<script>


  var config = {
     info
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);

    var fb = firebase.database().ref("posts/fun");

    var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase']);

    app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $firebaseArray, $timeout) {

        $scope.data = [];
        var _start = 0;
        var _end = 4;
        var _n = 5;

        $scope.getDataset = function() {

            fb.orderByChild('id').startAt(_start).endAt(_end).limitToLast(_n).on("child_added", function(dataSnapshot) {

                $scope.data.push(dataSnapshot.val());
                console.log("THE VALUE:"+$scope.data);

            });

            _start = _start + _n;
            _end = _end + _n;

        };


        $scope.getDataset()

    });

    // Compile the whole <body> with the angular module named "app"
    angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);


</script>


<div class ="containerMarginsIndex">

   <div ng-controller="ctrl">

            <div class="fun" ng-repeat="d in data">
                <h3 class="text-left">{{d.title}}</h3>
                    <div class = "postImgIndex">
                        <a href="details/{{d.id}}" target="_blank">
                            <img class= "imgIndex" ng-src="/images/uploads/{{d.image}}" >
                        </a>
                    </div> 
                <div class="postScore">{{d.upvotes - d.downvotes}} HP</div>
            </div>

    </div>

</div>

<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

---

**SITUATION:**

Ok, I have reworked my Firebase database architecture and changed the Firebase rules.

I am now certain the Firebase function returns a value (it is logged in the console).

But I still get the following error:

This HTML:

```
    <div class="fun" ng-repeat="d in data">
        <h3 class="text-left">{{d.title}}</h3>
            <div class = "postImgIndex">
                <a href="details/{{d.id}}" target="_blank">
                    <img class= "imgIndex" ng-src="/images/uploads/{{d.image}}" >
                </a>
            </div> 
        <div class="postScore">{{d.upvotes - d.downvotes}} HP</div>
    </div>
```

gets REPLACED by this once RENDERED:

```
<!-- ngRepeat: d in data --> == $0
```

What have I done wrong ?

Comment: That example is loading https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebase-util/0.2.5/firebase-util.min.js and https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.4/angularfire.min.js have you tried adding those?

Comment: @KevinLe Yes, doesn't work :(

Comment: @Kato Hello ! I am currently trying to implement one of your jsfiddles. Could you please have a look at my question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40565419/how-to-implement-infinite-scrolling-using-node-js-angular-js-and-firebase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not displaying in your view because you have nothing on the `$scope` and you're not using `{{}}` to interpolate your data. See the following changes:

Assign `data` to a `$scope` variable to be used in the view:

```
$scope.data = [];
var _start = 0;
var _end = 4;
var _n = 5;
var getDataset = function() {
  fb.orderByChild('time').startAt(_start).endAt(_end).limitToLast(_n).on("child_added", function(dataSnapshot) {
  $scope.data.push(dataSnapshot.val());
});

_start = _start + _n;
_end = _end + _n;
```

And your view, use `ngRepeat` and `{{}}` to interpolate:

```
<div class ="containerMarginsIndex">

          <div class="fun" ng-repeat="d in data">
            <h3 class="text-left">{{d.title}}</h3>
            <div class = "postImgIndex">
            <a href="details/{{post.id}}" target="_blank">
                <img class= "imgIndex" src="/images/uploads/{{post.image}}" >
            </a>
            </div> 
            <div class="postScore">({{d.upvotes - d.downvotes}}) HP</div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Not working yet, but making progress. Could you please have a look at update 6 ?

Comment: @Coder1000 - verify your data variable is actually populated. The comment means `data` is an empty array.

Comment: I just checked. getDataSet() seems to never get called. Even worse:  I tried calling it directly : `$scope.getDataset()` and still: nothing happened...

Comment: @Coder1000 -- Does your console statement get called inside the `getDataset` test? (The `console.log("4")`?

Comment: please have a look again at update 7, I just modified it :)

Comment: @Coder1000 -- Just looks like your firebase call isn't returning - I'm not too familiar with firebase, verify you have your credentials setup correctly and what not, and also see if you can add an error handler, then log the response.

Comment: Please have a look at Update 8, the Firebase problem has been solved.

Comment: @Coder1000 - Hah, nice on getting the firebase problem solved. I'm betting the issue now is your firebase call doesn't trigger a `$digest` cycle. Any reason why you're not using the `angular-firebase` module? (Oh, and test the above theory by calling `$scope.$apply()` once you're done pushing to `$scope.data` - note, `$scope.$apply()` shouldn't be considered a fix.

Comment: YESSSS ! YESSS! You were right !!!! THANK YOU :D But if it's not the (recommended) fix, what should I do ?

Comment: The recommended fix would be to use the `angular-firebase` module https://github.com/firebase/angularfire - this will trigger digest cycles correctly and safely - `$scope.$apply()` can be unsafe and cause errors - it has its uses though.

Comment: All right, please include this in your answer (including syntax to use angular-firebase) and I accept it :)

Comment: @Coder1000 -- Sorry man - I haven't really used Angular-fire - just checkout the github and go from there! Seems like your code above is already using `$firebaseArray`

Comment: Np. I'll get going >:D Thank you for your help ! Well deserved bounty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `$scope.$apply()` because the the scroll event executes outside Angular's context.

Also the event listener should be inside your controller so that the scoped `more` function is accessible.

Here's an updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xue8odfc/2/

I'd say the problem with Angular not resolving the `{{post.image}}` etc. is due to incompatibilities among the libraries you are referencing. I suggest testing using the versions from the working jsfiddle:

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.3/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebase-util/0.2.5/firebase-util.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.4/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ignoreScrollRetrieve is not defined(…)

Comment: I've updated the link. Please try again - https://jsfiddle.net/xue8odfc/2/

Comment: I also added in a variable to avoid any browser inaccuracies with the equals comparison. Just to be safe

Comment: The angular.js vars still don't get loaded :/

Comment: In my fiddle or your code?  Any error message in the console?

Comment: Yes, in the console I get 2 errors corresponding to the urls that load my image and some other element (obviously, since instead of the image name, "post.image" gets passed in)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128212/discussion-between-k-scandrett-and-coder1000).

Comment: I couldn't get my jsfiddle to work using your versions of the libraries (it just showed `{{rawdata | json}}` on the page), so I expect the problem is incompatibilities there. Refer my edit above for compatible libraries to try

Comment: Didn't work. It actually didn't change the outcome  :(

Answer (score 1):

Add your scroll listener within your controller. The function `more` does not exist indeed, however you do have a `$scope.more` method.

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $firebaseArray, $timeout) {

    // ORDERED BY TIME:
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("posts/fun");
    var scrollRef = new Firebase.util.Scroll(ref, "time");
    $scope.posts = $firebaseArray(scrollRef);
    scrollRef.scroll.next(5);

    // AS DATA APPEARS IN DATABASE ORDERED BY TIME:
    ref.once('value', function(snap) {
        $scope.rawdata = snap.val();
        $scope.$apply();
    });

    $scope.more = function() {
       scrollRef.scroll.next(5);
    };

    // Add scroll listener
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
      if (window.scrollY === document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight) {
        $scope.$apply($scope.more);
      } 
    });
});
```

Note that I am calling `$scope.more` within `$scope.$apply` so that the scope is digested at the end of the call. Indeed a JS listener on a window scroll event is out of the Angular lifecycle so we need to manually `$digest` the scope for Angular to update all its watchers and update the HTML. Search online about `$scope.$apply` if you want to learn more about it.

### **About your first problem**

Your angular application is not started because angular is never initialized. For that you need either to load it synchronously and use the `ng-app` directive, or if you don't want to change anything with your code you can simply add these lines after your module and controller definition:

```
// Compile the whole <body> with the angular module named "app"
angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

Comment: I think your code works, but my angular vars still don't get replaced with their actual values   :/ Would you know what caused this ? (I am completely new to Angular.js)

Comment: @Coder1000 indeed I have updated my answer regarding your first problem. Try angular.boostrap on the body or on the element that contains your ng-controller

Comment: angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element(…)

Comment: @Coder1000 try to replace `angular.elment('body')` by `document.body`, ie `angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);`

Comment: angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module firebase due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'firebase' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Ok, I fixed that by adding angularfire, but I still have this error:  `http://localhost:3000/images/uploads/%7B%7Bpost.image%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @Coder1000 that's better. Now your application is starting and Angular fails to load the `firebase` module. That is because it does not exist. The jsfiddle you provided seems to include a file named `angularfire.min.js` (https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.4/angularfire.min.js). Try to load that as it probably defines the firebase module.

Comment: @Coder1000 can you copy paste that in your browser: `http://localhost:3000/images/uploads/%7B%7Bpost.image%7D%7D`? If you don't see the image then it means it is not present and the URL you generate is wrong. I cannot really help with that, it is totally unrelated with Angular and your infinite scrolling issue

Comment: Actually, the url is correct, it's just that the post.image var doesn't resolve to the actual value of the image :/ So, it is a problem related to angular.js

Comment: Oh I see. Use `ng-src` instead of `src` in your img tag and that should be better. `ng-src="/images/uploads/{{post.image}}"`

Comment: I no longer get the error, but if I look at the rendered html, I see this: `<img class="imgIndex" ng-src="/images/uploads/{{post.image}}">` instead of post.image being replaced with the actual id of the image.

Comment: @Coder1000 do you see the image or not? Below the <img> tag try adding some `<div>{{post.image}}</div>` and see if this is correctly replaced by the content of post.image. `ng-src` should behave the same if yes, otherwise there is a problem somewhere else

Comment: I dont' see the image at all :/ Regardless, my other vars (post.title, post.downvote, post.upvote) don't resolve either :(  (I am a complete newbie to angular, so please don't discard any "obvious" explanation)

Comment: @Coder1000 and if you do a console.log($scope.posts) do you get an array of posts that contain image, downvote, upvote, etc? Make sure the data is right. If you could provide a JSfiddle with what you have so far I could keep helping you from there. Maybe start by hardcoding `$scope.posts = [{title: 'test'}]` and see if that works, then once that works you can start to integrate firebase etc. Try to isolate your problems one by one. I need to go to sleep now, will resume tomorrow. You can also open new questions as this is slightly different than your initial question. Good luck!

Comment: I actually consider it to be in the scope of my question, but thx for your help ! I upvoted your answer to thank you for your time. And if your debugging advice yields me the answer, I will accept your answer and award the bounty. Sleep well ! (And see you tomorrow if I don't find the answer)

Comment: Updated my question with more info. It seems the code inside `app.controller` never gets executed :(

Comment: You don't have any error left? Does the code around this controller executes? (add a console.log before `app.controller(....)` and after it). I would start by removing all the controller code and the firebase stuff and just add `$scope.test = "ok"`, really just that, and your html as simple as `<div>{{test}}</div>` and see if that works. Again you need to start with something simple and add more code little by little, checking that it still works in between

Comment: Ok, I did that. Please check UPDATE 2 to my question :)

Comment: @Coder1000 I went down to update 6, it appear your `$scope.data` array is empty. Are you sure you get to do `$scope.data.push(...)` at least once? Your function `$scope.getDataset` which populates the array is bound to the scroll but never it is never called? Could you call it at least once manually, `$scope.getDataset()`. You are not focusing on one problem but are basically asking us to follow you until the end of your project, this is not what SO is intended for.

Comment: I tried calling it directly, nothing happens.  I get 0 errors or warnings in the console or the terminal.

Comment: You need to find out why no item is added to your `$scope.data` array. Try adding some manually to see if they are visible in the HTML. I am repeating myself but you need to do things gradually.

Comment: Please have a look at Update 8, the Firebase problem has been solved.

Comment: Glad you had your problem fixed. I helped you go through 6 different issues but I guess the award was for the one giving you the last fix. Well whatever :p cheers

Comment: Well, he gave me many fixes and the one that solved my problem, but I did upvote your answer to thank you for you time :)